# How to correctly set layout using example below

Tags: php, html

So lets say below are the correct and incorrect answers for each question:

```
Question Number: 1   Correct Answer(s) B     Incorrect Answers A C D
Question Number: 2   Correct Answer(s) A C   Incorrect Answers B D
Question Number: 3   Correct Answer(s) D     Incorrect Answers A B C
```

Below shows the current layout and the way it should be laid out:

[image]

The code for the current output is this:

```
<table border='1' id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionNo);
$prev_ques = '';
foreach($searchQuestionNo as $key=>$questionNo){

?>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <?php
    if($questionNo != $prev_ques){
    ?>
    <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo$row_span[$questionNo]?>">
    <?php echo$questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo$questionNo?>" />
    </td>
    <?php
    }  
    ?>
<td class="answertd"><?php echo implode(',', $incorrect_ans[$key]);?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$prev_ques = $questionNo;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so your problem is with the html table display?

Comment: @Roy yes the problem is the way the data is displayed in the table

Comment: Removed the `php` and `mysqli` tags.

Comment: @njk I agree with removing `mysqli`, but as the OP is generating the html and table using php `foreach` and `implode`, I believe the `php` tag is valid.

Comment: have posted an answer according to your ques, if you have already got your answer its gud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change your current table structure to your desired table structure you need to modify-
(1) the `rowspan` in each your `<td class="questionnumtd">` and
(2) how you echo your `<td class="answertd">`'s

The easiest is the `<td class="answertd">`. Change

```
    <td class="answertd"><?php echo implode(',', $incorrect_ans[$key]);?></td>
</tr>
```

to

```
    <?php
    foreach($incorrect_ans[$key] as $answer){ ?>
            <td class="answertd"><?php echo$answer?></td>
           </tr>
    <?php
    }
```

The `<td class="questionnumtd">` `rowspan` is a little harder as in your current table structure & code you show that there is 2 rows of `$incorrect_ans[$key]` for question 2. Using the `foreach` loop below, it sets a question rowspan `$q_row_span[$i]` based off all the `$incorrect_ans[$key]`

```
$q_counter = 1;// counter for $row_span
$i = key($row_span);  // gets first question number
foreach ($incorrect_ans as $key => $val){
    if($q_counter == 1){
        $q_row_span[$i] = count($val);}
    else{
        $q_row_span[$i] += count($val);}
    if($q_counter >= $row_span[$i]){
        $q_counter = 1;
        $i++;}
    else{
        $q_counter++; }
}
```

---

Try -

```
<table border='1' id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionNo);
    $q_counter = 1;// counter for $row_span
    $i = key($row_span);  // gets first question number
    foreach ($incorrect_ans as $key => $val){
        if($q_counter == 1){
            $q_row_span[$i] = count($val);}
        else{
            $q_row_span[$i] += count($val);}
        if($q_counter >= $row_span[$i]){
            $q_counter = 1;
            $i++;}
        else{
            $q_counter++; }
    }
$prev_ques = '';
foreach($searchQuestionNo as $key=>$questionNo){

?>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <?php
    if($questionNo != $prev_ques){
    ?>
    <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo$q_row_span[$questionNo]?>">
    <?php echo$questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo$questionNo?>" />
    </td>
    <?php
    }  

    foreach($incorrect_ans[$key] as $answer){ ?>
    <td class="answertd"><?php echo$answer?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
$prev_ques = $questionNo;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

See this phpfiddle that shows your original structure, and the new structure with the code above. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z8e-74b

Comment: That was a brilliant effort. To Be honest you are nearly there, the issue is that it is display for incorrect answers for question 2, `B, C, D A, B, D` or in other words it is retrieving one correct answer for first row then displaying the other incorrect answers for that row, then it retrieving answer from second row and displaying its incorrect answers like you have mentioned that could be the problem. The incorrect answers for question 2 is `B, D` as they appear in both rows for incorrect answers for that question

Comment: Since your issue is the number of answers for question 2, you need to look at how you are setting/populating `$incorrect_ans[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

here is exactly what you want your output to be like

```
<?php
$incorrect_ans = array(
                   array('A','C','D'),
                   array('B','C','D'),
                   array('A','B','D'),
                   array('A','B','C'));

$searchQuestionNo = array(
                   1,
                   2,
                   2,
                   3);

$ques_ans = array();    //to store incorrect answers against ques no.

$q_occ_count = array_count_values($searchQuestionNo);
foreach($searchQuestionNo as $key => $questionNo)
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists($questionNo, $ques_ans))
    {
        if($q_occ_count[$questionNo] === 1) //if a ques has only one correct ans
        {
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = $incorrect_ans[$key];  //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key 
        }
        else //if a ques has more than 1 correct ans
        {
            //find the intersection of incorrect_ans arrays for this ques
            $q_keys = array_keys($searchQuestionNo, $questionNo);
            $q_incorrect_ans = $incorrect_ans[$q_keys[0]];
            foreach($q_keys as $q_key) {
                $q_incorrect_ans = array_intersect($q_incorrect_ans, $incorrect_ans[$q_key]);
            }       
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = $q_incorrect_ans;  //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key
        }
    }
}
var_dump($ques_ans);
?>
<table border='1' id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($ques_ans as $questionNo => $inc_ans)
{
    $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
    ?>
    <tr class="questiontd">
        <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo $questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo $q_row_span ?>">
                <?php echo $questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo $questionNo?>" />
        </td>
        <?php

        foreach ($inc_ans as $ans)
        {
        ?>
            <td class="answertd"><?php echo $ans; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7j1-we2)**

the code above works even if you are having 3 correct answers