# How to loops through set of answers once and display only incorrect answers

Tags: php, html

So lets say below are the correct and incorrect answers for each question:

```
Question Number: 1   Correct Answer(s) B     Incorrect Answers A C D
Question Number: 2   Correct Answer(s) A C   Incorrect Answers B D
Question Number: 3   Correct Answer(s) D     Incorrect Answers A B C
```

The problem is the way I am retreiving the incorrect answers for a question which has multiple answers (multiple correct answers). Retrieving incorrect answers where a question just has a single correct answer does not have any problems, just multiple correct answers.

Below shows the current way the incorrect answers are displayed and the way it should look like (I color coded below so you can see where the issue is):

[image]

If there are multiple correct answers in a question, it seems like what it does within that question that it just loops through all the answer, remove one correct answer and display the rest of the answers, and then it loops through all answers again and removes another one correct answer and display the rest of the current answers.

So it recognizes A and C were correct answers as that it removed `A` from first set of incorrect answers it displays in question 2 and it removed `C` from second set of incorrect answers in question 2. But like I said this is incorrect display, it should just display an incorrect answer in each row per question.

My question is how can the display be fixed to match what it should look like?

The code for the current output is this:

```
<table border='1' id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionNo);
    $q_counter = 1;// counter for $row_span
    $i = key($row_span);  // gets first question number
    foreach ($incorrect_ans as $key => $val){
        if($q_counter == 1){
            $q_row_span[$i] = count($val);}
        else{
            $q_row_span[$i] += count($val);}
        if($q_counter >= $row_span[$i]){
            $q_counter = 1;
            $i++;}
        else{
            $q_counter++; }
    }
$prev_ques = '';
foreach($searchQuestionNo as $key=>$questionNo){

?>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <?php
    if($questionNo != $prev_ques){
    ?>
    <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo$q_row_span[$questionNo]?>">
    <?php echo$questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo$questionNo?>" />
    </td>
    <?php
    }  

    foreach($incorrect_ans[$key] as $answer){ ?>
    <td class="answertd"><?php echo$answer?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
$prev_ques = $questionNo;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The code below shows how it retrieves the incorrect answers for each question and then stores it in the array. This piece of code is displayed above the HTML table above:

```
$specialOptionTypes = array('Yes or No' => array( 'Yes', 'No' ),'True or False' => array( 'True', 'False' ));

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

// Do this for each row:
if ( array_key_exists( $dbOptionType, $specialOptionTypes ) ) {
    $options = $specialOptionTypes[$dbOptionType];
} else if ( preg_match( '/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $dbOptionType, $match ) ) {
    $options = range( $match[1], $match[2] );
} else {
    // issue warning about unrecognized option type
    $options = array();
}
$right = str_split( $dbAnswer ); 
$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right );  

        $searchQuestionNo[] = $dbQuestionNo;
        $incorrect_ans[] = $wrong;
      }
```

**UPDATE:**

What happens if there is additional column after `Incorrect Answer` column, code below messes up the layout:

```
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($ques_ans as $questionNo => $inc_ans)
{
    $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
    ?>
    <tr class="questiontd">
        <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo $questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo $q_row_span ?>">
                <?php echo $questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo $questionNo?>" />
        </td>
        <?php

        foreach ($inc_ans as $ans)
        {
        ?>
            <td class="answertd"><?php echo $ans; ?></td>
          <?php  
            }
          ?>         
            <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo $questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo $q_row_span ?>">
        <?php echo $questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo $questionNo?>" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Show us where you define `$incorrect_ans`.

Comment: How is your $incorrect_ans array structured?  Something like this?  {1 => {'A', 'C', 'D'}, 2 => {'B', 'D'}, 3 => {'A', 'B', 'D'}?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst $incorrect_ans is defined above the table as an array, I included an update showing the code on how I retrieve the incorrect answers and how I remove the correct answers for each question and then store it in the array

Comment: @JLRishe included update showing var dump post of what you stated

Comment: Could you provide just `var_dump($incorrect_ans)`, without the `$key`?

Comment: @JLRishe I change the var_dump to $incorrect_ans and displayed results in update

Comment: Sorry for the repeated requests, but could you show us a dump of `$searchQuestionNo`? What is the purpose of `$searchQuestionNo`?

Comment: here is the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266437/how-to-correctly-set-layout-using-example-below/14290673#14290673 to same ques u have asked, just check out my answer

Comment: @Uttara do you want to move your answer to this question so I can mark it as best answer. I didn't mean to ask it like another layout question, I was suppose to ask about why it loops through each set of answers multiple times if there are multiple answers. But to show what I meant I had to display the layout. Thanks

Comment: @Uttara Just to save me from asking another question on this I just have one little issue, lets say my table has and additional column which is like the `QuestionNo` column where it has to be rowspan, then how do I fix the layout so it can simply just add that column correctly next to `Incorrect Answer` column. It is because you foreach loop which checks for answer rows finishs after table row, but this column will not be final column. I included update at bottom of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is exactly what you want your output to be like

```
<?php
$incorrect_ans = array(
                   array('A','C','D'),
                   array('B','C','D'),
                   array('A','B','D'),
                   array('A','B','C'));

$searchQuestionNo = array(
                   1,
                   2,
                   2,
                   3);

$ques_ans = array();    //to store incorrect answers against ques no.

$q_occ_count = array_count_values($searchQuestionNo);
foreach($searchQuestionNo as $key => $questionNo)
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists($questionNo, $ques_ans))
    {
        if($q_occ_count[$questionNo] === 1) //if a ques has only one correct ans
        {
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = $incorrect_ans[$key];  //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key 
        }
        else //if a ques has more than 1 correct ans
        {
            //find the intersection of incorrect_ans arrays for this ques
            $q_keys = array_keys($searchQuestionNo, $questionNo);
            $q_incorrect_ans = $incorrect_ans[$q_keys[0]];
            foreach($q_keys as $q_key) {
                $q_incorrect_ans = array_intersect($q_incorrect_ans, $incorrect_ans[$q_key]);
            }       
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = $q_incorrect_ans;  //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key
        }
    }
}
var_dump($ques_ans);
?>
<table border='1' id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($ques_ans as $questionNo => $inc_ans)
{
    $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
    ?>
    <tr class="questiontd">
        <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo $questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo $q_row_span ?>">
                <?php echo $questionNo?><input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo $questionNo?>" />
        </td>
        <?php

        foreach ($inc_ans as $ans)
        {
        ?>
            <td class="answertd"><?php echo $ans; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7j1-we2)**

the code above works even if you are having 3 correct answers

**Update**

not adding code here, just done few modifications
**[updated Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps)**

Comment: Just to save me from asking another question on this I just have one little issue, lets say my table has and additional column which is like the QuestionNo column where it has to be rowspan, then how do I fix the layout so it can simply just add that column correctly next to Incorrect Answer column. It is because you foreach loop which checks for answer rows finishs after table row, but this column will not be final column. I included update at bottom of question

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
foreach($searchQuestionNo as $key => $qNum)
{
    $answers = $incorrect_ans[$key];
    $aCount = count($answers);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($answers as $answer)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        if($i == 0)
        {
           echo "<td class='questionnumtd q{$qNum}_qnum' rowspan='$aCount'>$qNum";
           echo "<input type='hidden' name='numQuestion' value='$qNum' />";
           echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "<td class='answertd'>$answer</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/7asOjm

Comment: This has not quite done it, I included an update 2 in my question which shows screenshot on results of the table so you can see what the output looks like as well as the `var_dump($answers[i]);`

Comment: I've made a modification to take into account the irregular indices on $incorrect_ans[$key].  Could you try it now?

Comment: @JL I updated update 2 to show results now, it is still not showing right display. To be honest I think my table layout is correct as it displays only question number once for each qustion, I think the issue maybe is the way I collect the answers from a question which has multiple answers. I think my function which separates right and wrong answers does it in a way that if there is multiple answers, it will display all answers, remove one answer, then it will display all answers again but this time remove another one correct answer

Comment: I think this is what is doing for question 2 in the function: `display A, B , C, D, remove correct answer A, display A, B, C, D, remove correct answer C.` It is better if it can just do: `display A, B, C , D, remove correct answer A, remove correct answer C`

Comment: Ok, so it looks like your logic for building the $incorrect_ans array in the first place has an issue, and not the initial code you showed us (though it was rather messy).

Comment: Yeah looking at it now that seems the case, it has been fixed now anyway